# Wrong value of sum using fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the following $2 \pi $ periodic function which is $t$ for $0\leq t <\pi$ and $0$ for $\pi\leq t<2\pi$

I'm asked to find its complex fourier series representation. So I calculate 
$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}te^{-ikt}dt$ which results in $\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{\pi(-1)^k}{-ik}+\frac{(-1)^k-1}{k^2})$ and $c_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}tdt=\frac{\pi}{4}$. So our complex fourier series is

$f(t)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{-\infty, k\neq 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{\pi(-1)^k}{-ik}+\frac{(-1)^k-1}{k^2})e^{ikt}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{-\infty, k\neq 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{(-1)^k-1}{k^2})e^{ikt}$

Then I am asked to find the value of the fourier series at $t=\pi$. 
In their solution, they simply say that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

But I don't see how they got there. 
 Plugging in $\pi$, I get:
$f(\pi)=0=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{-\infty, k\neq 0}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{\pi k^2}*(-1)$ for $k$ odd. Now, if I solve, I get $\frac{-\pi^2}{4}$

So I don't see what I did wrong and how they got $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The value will definitely be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as it will be the average value at the jump in $f(t)$ from $\pi$ to 0 when $t = \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard result that the Fourier series evaluated at a jump discontinuity of the (otherwise nice) function is the average of the left and right limits. So, here, that should be the average of $\pi$ from below and $0$ from above, or $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The solution you mention checks out.

So, where did your calculation go wrong?

You've got the right coefficients.

That series for $f(t)$ - the $\frac1k$ terms don't go away just yet. Those correspond to the odd part of $f$ ($\frac t2$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$). We can't drop them until we choose $\pi$ as the point to evaluate at - because there, $e^{ik\pi}=e^{-ik\pi}$ and terms on opposite sides of zero cancel for a principal value sum of zero.

Plugging in $\pi$ - that's a correct expression. And I get $\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for it. Your error is somewhere in that last step, for which you didn't show any work.

Comment: Well, in the last step, I put the $\frac{\pi}{4}$ on the other side and then solved for $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$, k odd. I think that's the problem

Comment: Just a question, to get the second $\frac{\pi}{4}$, you seem to have evaluated                $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2m+1)^2}$ whose value is $ \frac{\pi^2}{8}$ then used the fact that we have $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}=2 \sum_{0}^{\infty}$. Do you think they supposed we should know the value of that sum ?

Comment: It does seem rather necessary for this one. Of course, we can easily derive it from the well-known sum of all the reciprocals of squares.

Answer (score 1):

Your series serms correct, but I am at a loss as to how you got $(-\pi^2)/4$.

If you know the reciprocal square sum

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^2)=\pi^2/6$

then you can subtract one quarter of that:

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/(2n)^2)=\pi^2/24$

and thus

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^2)|_{n\text{ odd}}=\pi^2/8$.

Plug that into your sum, remembering that there is also a division by $\pi$, and the correct solution should come out.